# Implement Time in Milliseconds for Cross platform in Delphi

Tags: delphi, cross-platform

I have a piece of code in Delphi (in Windows) which I have implemented for cross platform using RAD Studio.
Here is the code:

```
uses SysUtils, Windows, DateUtils;

type
  TSystem_Time = record
    wYear: word;
    wMonth: word;
    wDayOfWeek: word;
    wDay: word;
    wHour: word;
    wMinute: word;
    wSecond: word;
    wMilliseconds: word;
  end;

function DatumInSeconds2(y, m, d, h, mi, s: word): longword;
var
  RelDay: longword;
begin
  if y >= 1970 then
    dec(y, 1900)
  else if y < 70 then
    inc(y, 100); // 00..69 -> 100..169
  if (y < 70) or (y > 169) or (m < 1) or (m > 12) or (d < 1) or (d > 31) then
  begin
    DatumInSeconds2 := 0;
    exit;
  end;
  while m > 1 do
  begin
    dec(m);
    d := d + DaysInMonth[m];
    if (m = 2) and ((y mod 4) = 0) then
      inc(d); { gilt auch fuer Jahr 2000 }
  end;
  RelDay := longword(365) * longword(y - 70) + // Tage in den Vorjahren
    longword((y - 69) div 4) + // Schalttage in den Vorjahren
    d - 1;
  DatumInSeconds2 := ((RelDay * longword(24) + h) * longword(60) + mi) *
    longword(60) + s
end;

function GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Windows: Int64; // For windows
var
  stt: TSystemTime;
  secFrom1900: Int64;
  UtcSystemTime: TSystemTime;
  LocalFileTime: TFileTime;
  UTCFileTime: TFileTime;

begin
  Writeln('Enter GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Windows');
  GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Windows := 0;
  { W1035 Return value of function 'GetTimeInMilliSeconds' might be undefined }
  GetSystemTime(stt);
  SystemTimeToFileTime(stt, LocalFileTime);
  // Local System Time -> Local File Time
  if LocalFileTimeToFileTime(LocalFileTime, UTCFileTime) then
    // Local File Time -> UTC File Time
    if FileTimeToSystemTime(UTCFileTime, UtcSystemTime) then
    begin // Local File Time -> UTC System Time
      with UtcSystemTime do
      begin
        secFrom1900 := DatumInSeconds2(wYear, wMonth, wDay, wHour, wMinute,
          wSecond) + 2208988800;
        Writeln('secFrom1900', secFrom1900);
        Writeln('wYear', wYear);
        Writeln('wMonth', wMonth);
        Writeln('wDay', wDay);
        Writeln('wHour', wHour);
        Writeln('wMinute', wMinute);
        Writeln('wSecond', wSecond);
        Writeln('wMilliseconds', wMilliseconds);
        GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Windows := (secFrom1900 * 1000) + wMilliseconds;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      // In case the conversion to UTC fails, return the timestamp in local time.
      with stt do
      begin
        secFrom1900 := DatumInSeconds2(wYear, wMonth, wDay, wHour, wMinute,
          wSecond) + 2208988800;
        GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Windows := (secFrom1900 * 1000) + wMilliseconds;
      end;
    end;
end;

function GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Crossplatform: Int64; // crossplatform code
var
  dtNow, newdt: TDateTime;
  st: TSystem_Time;
  secFrom1900: Int64;

begin
  Writeln('Enter GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Crossplatform');
  GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Crossplatform := 0;
  dtNow := Now;
  newdt := TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(dtNow);
  DecodeDateTime(newdt, st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wHour, st.wMinute,
    st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
  with st do
  begin
    secFrom1900 := DatumInSeconds2(wYear, wMonth, wDay, wHour, wMinute, wSecond)
      + 2208988800;
    // secFrom1900:= DateTimeToUnix(newdt) + 2208988800;
    Writeln('secFrom1900', secFrom1900);
    Writeln('wYear', wYear);
    Writeln('wMonth', wMonth);
    Writeln('wDay', wDay);
    Writeln('wHour', wHour);
    Writeln('wMinute', wMinute);
    Writeln('wSecond', wSecond);
    Writeln('wMilliseconds', wMilliseconds);
    GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Crossplatform := (secFrom1900 * 1000) +
      st.wMilliseconds;
  end;
end;
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Windows
secFrom19003830898396
wYear2021
wMonth5
wDay25
wHour2
wMinute26
wSecond36
wMilliseconds551
Original_GetTimeInMilliSeconds>>3830898396551
sec3830898396
Enter GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Crossplatform
secFrom19003830918196
wYear2021
wMonth5
wDay25
wHour7
wMinute56
wSecond36
wMilliseconds560
Test_GetTimeInMilliSeconds>>3830918196560
```

So the issue here is when I try to execute them both differs in hour and Minute. Can anyone suggest some idea how to resolve this? or may be some another approach is needed to implement it?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Is the difference constant? If it is, what is the value? If it isn't what kind of differences?

Comment: It seems like the `if` branches don't do what you expect, because the actual interpretation differs from the one suggested by your indentation. The actual interpretation is `if LocalFileTimeToFileTime then do X` where `X` is `if FileTimeToSystemTime then A else B`. So, if not `LocalFileTimeToFileTime`, then you do nothing. (And so the compiler's W1035 is absolutely right: without your `:= 0`, the returned value would be random garbage, and the caller has no way to realise this.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - you're not suggesting that the use of parenthesis here would make things clearer are you!

Comment: @RobLambden: No, but a correct understanding of the Pascal syntax as well as proper indentation. And, to be fair, I do realise the use of superfluous `begin..end`s would help beginners avoid this kind of mistake.

Comment: @fpiette posted the output

Comment: Fixed indentation and swapped orders of declaration so it can be compiled.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand " I do realise the use of superfluous begin..ends would help beginners avoid this kind of mistake". Not just beginners. As a matter of course I use superfluous begin/end to avoid this kind of mistake and I have been programming  in Delphi for over 20 years. It saves so much maintenance time.

Comment: @Dsm: I don't know why, but I haven't made any such mistake the last 10 years. I do got an autism diagnosis, though, so my brain is very focused on details.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand And I am sure many haven't. To each their own. I am sure I would be able to do the same. I just choose not to.

Comment: @Anna The difference you show is exactly 05h30. It looks like [Indian Standard Time](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heure_normale_de_l%27Inde) It means it is an issue with local time versus UTC.

Comment: @fpiette   So is there any API which converts to UTC time or viceversa in Delphi .Any idea on the same?

Comment: @Anna You can get time zone information using `GetTimeZoneInformation`. You'll be interested in Bias, DayLightBias, StandardBias. Look at `function TimeZoneBias` at http://svn.overbyte.be/svn/ics/trunk/Source/OverbyteIcsSmtpProt.pas (Use username = ics and password = ics for read access).

Comment: @fpiette GetTimeZoneInformation() is windows API. Here I am looking for crossplatform or Linux if possible.

Comment: @TomBrunberg yes its UTC time but with that not getting the correct output. Instead if I pass dtNow to DecodeDateTime() then I am getting in the output Hour like:
wHour17   which is the only parameter different in both the functions.

Comment: @anna Do you know that Delphi comes with RTL source code? I searched `GetTimeZoneInformation` in Delphi source code and found it in System.DateUtils at two places. There are conditional compilation for Windows, MacOS and Posix (Linux). So I see that the equavalent for Linux is `localtime_r`. I also understand that you should make use a [TTimeZone class](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils.TTimeZone)

Comment: @TomBrunberg I just want to achieve the same functionality as implemented in GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Windows() function  based on any time (local time or UTC).
secondly , I am not storing time in any DB or file . I have some macros defined in my application which reads the time and store in some variable to process further.
Thirdly, this is a legacy code , it is implemented like that only so I need to maintain it and as I told this milliseconds time is storing in some variable acting as macro which needs to be in milliseconds only.

Comment: @TomBrunberg This is the purpose of the function GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Windows()
"Returns the current timestamp since 1/1/1900 in milliseconds. This is to be used for timestamp in NTP format." This is the comment/explanation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First about the error in your current `function GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Windows: Int64;`. The error is not a fixed 3 hours as I said. It is 3 hours for me as I live in Finland and our time zone is UTC + 2 hours + 1 hour DST. The error is the same as the diff between UTC time and local time.

The error happens because you call two different functions that convert/return from local time to UTC. Below the function calls and a brief description from MSDN.

> `GetSystemTime(stt);` - Retrieves the current system date and time in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) format

> result: 2021, 5, 2, 25, 15, 23, 39, 219,   Time: 15.23.39. My actual local time is 18.23.39

> `SystemTimeToFileTime(stt, LocalFileTime);` - Converts a system time to file time format. System time is based on Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

> `LocalFileTimeToFileTime(LocalFileTime, UTCFileTime)` - Converts a local file time to a file time based on the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

> `FileTimeToSystemTime(UTCFileTime, UtcSystemTime)` - Converts a file time to system time format. System time is based on Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

> result: 2021, 5, 2, 25, 12, 23, 39, 219,   Time: 12.23.39

This is my suggestion for a better (in my mind) solution. As you did not say what kind of use cases you have you may have to apply it as needed. Anyway, the result is nr of milliseconds since beginning of 1900.

```
function GetTimeInMilliSeconds_Crossplatform: Int64;
var
  dtNow: TDateTime;
  epoch: TDatetime;
  st: TSystemTime;
  secsbetween, msecsBetween: int64;
begin
  // define
  epoch := EncodeDateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

  // get current local date time
  dtNow := Now;
  // Memo1.Lines.Add('DtToS, loc: '+DateTimeToStr(dtNow));

  // or get current date time as UTC
  dtNow := TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now);
  // Memo1.Lines.Add('DtToS, utc: '+DateTimeToStr(dtNow));

  // Convert to date and time record if required
  DecodeDateTime(dtNow, st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);

  // convert to milliseconds from 1900.01.01 00.00.00
  msecsBetween := MilliSecondsBetween(dtNow, epoch);
  // Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Milliseconds since epoch = %d',[msecsBetween]));
  
  result := msecsBetween;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It helps.